# Metodo no permitido al acceder a una API REST

Tags: rest, symfony3

Buenas tengo un problemilla que me tiene desesperado, a ver si alguien puede echarme una mano, la situación es la siguiente.

Tengo una API REST en Symfony 3, que consumo con un front Angular, la aplicación en conjunto funciona perfectamente en un servidor Apache que tengo en local, pero al subirlo a un servidor gratuito que tengo en Hostinger, solo me funcionan las peticiones GET, las POST me dan el siguiente error

```
GET "ruta" 405 (Method Not Allowed)
```

Por lo que he estado viendo todo apunta a un error CORS, creo que vale la pena mencionar que obtengo el mismo resultado desde Postman, el cliente Restfull de chrome, por lo que descartado que sea un error de las peticiones de angular, centrandome en la configuración del backend, tengo lo sigiente:

En el frontcontroler tengo desde que subí por primera vez la aplicación el siguiente código:

```
header ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header ("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, 
Content-Type, Accept, Access-Control-Request-Method");
header ("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
header ("Allow: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
$method = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
if ($method == "OPTIONS"){
 die ();
}
```

Como me dio el error mencionado y despues de buscar por internet agregué el siguiente archivo .htacces:

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

Como el error persistía opté por añadir el siguiente código en el controlador concreto de Symfony al que estoy accediendo al obtener el error:

```
$respuesta =  new JsonResponse($registro);
$response->setContent($respuesta);
$response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
$response->headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
return $response;
```

Sigue sin funcionar, no se que más probar, empiezo a sospechar que hostinger tenga limitado esto de alguna forma, pero no sé como, o si esto es posible, lo que sí se que los archivos .htaccess (en general) están habilitados por que tengo otros funcionando en otras carpetas.

Si a alguien se le ocurre que puede estar fallando, agradeceré cualquier aportación.

Edito: Si quereis ver la aplicacion en funcionamiento esta en http://www.proyotb.esy.es/cursoFullStack/ para ver el error darle a "acceder" arriba a la derecha e intentar hacer login.

codigo del controlador:

```
<?php
   namespace AppBundle\Controller;
   use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
   use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
   use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
   use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
   use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

  class DefaultController extends Controller{

     public function indexAction(Request $request){
       // replace this example code with whatever you need
       return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', [
        'base_dir' => realpath($this->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..'),]);
    }

   public function loginAction (Request $request){
        $helpers = $this->get("app.helpers");
        $jwt_auth = $this->get("app.jwt_auth");

        $json = $request->get("json", null);
        if ($json != null){
           $params = json_decode($json);

           $email = (isset ($params->email)) ? $params->email : null;
           $password = (isset ($params->password)) ? $params->password : null;
           $getHash = (isset ($params->getHash)) ? $params->getHash : null;
           $emailConstrain = new Assert\Email();
           $emailConstrain->message = "El email no es valido";

           $validate_email = $this->get("validator")->validate ($email, $emailConstrain);

           //cifrar password
           $pwd = hash ("sha256", $password);

           if (count ($validate_email) == 0 && $password != null){
               if ($getHash == NULL || $getHash == "false"){
                   $signup = $jwt_auth->signup($email, $pwd);
               }else{
                   $signup = $jwt_auth->signup($email, $pwd, true);
               }
               return new JsonResponse($signup);
               //echo "Datos conseguidos!!";
           }else{
               return $helpers->json(array(
                "status" => "error",
                "data" => "Login Incorrecto!!"
            ));

           }
        }else{
            return $helpers->json(array(
                "status" => "error",
                "data" => "Envia JSON por POST!!"
              ));
        }

   }
}
```

pongo tambien el archivo yml correspondiente a as rutas per si era lo que querias ver:

```
default_index:
    path: /
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Default:index"}
    methods: GET

default_login:
    path: /login
    defaults: { _controller: "AppBundle:Default:login"}
    methods: POST
```

codigo de la peticion angular:

```
 signup(user_to_login) {
      let json = JSON.stringify (user_to_login);
      let params = "json="+json;
      let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'});
      let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
      return this._http.post (this.url+'/login', params, options)
                .map(res=> res.json());
 }
```

Comment: Podrías postear la función del controlador con las anotaciones correspondientes? Normalmente esto me ha pasado por no poner la anotación method o por problemas de crossdomain/cors mal configurado

Comment: Ya he editado para incluir el codigo del archivo, la ruta va a loginAction y esta configurada en un archivo yaml. lo más extraño de todo es que en un servidor apache que tengo en local funciona correctamente, pero estoy abierto a cualquier sugeriencia, que tendria que poner exactamente  con las anotaciones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al hacer inicio de sesión está enviando un `GET`, pero veo que tu **routing.yml** solo acepta `POST`. He probado a hacer una petición `POST` vacía y me da un `error interno 500`, por lo que parece que la petición llega al controlador.

Solución: Cambiar el método de la petición de `GET` a `POST`.

Comment: Gracias por los aportes, te cuento, he probado varias veces y a mi me sigue dando el dichoso 405 desde postman con una peticion POST, quiza fue un error puntal del servidor ese 500 que te dio, la dirección a la que hay que enviar la peticion es esta

Comment: http://www.proyotb.esy.es/cursoFullStack/symfony/web/app.php/login

Comment: El tema de una petición GET en lugar de POST he revisado el codigo y la peticion es POST tambien y como ya dije desde postman especificando metodo POST sigo recibiendo 405, en cualquier caso edito el comentario inicial para que puedas ver el codigo de la petición angular, en cualquier caso creo que en esta situacion deberia responderme symfony advirtiendo del error y el que esta contestando es el servidor apache, ademas ten en cuenta que estoy recibiendo tambien 405 en postman.

Comment: Me resulta extraño que le pongas un header application/x-www-form-urlencoded, pero luego envies un json y esperes un json como respuesta. ¿Esa cabecera no debería ser "application/json"?

Comment: Por cierto, cuando hago la petición POST, el error que recibo es este:

Comment: <br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function setContent() on null in <b>/home/u737470708/public_html/cursoFullStack/symfony/src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php</b> on line <b>63</b><br />
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  realpath(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/opt/php) is not within the allowed path(s): (/home/u737470708:/tmp:/var/tmp:/opt/php-5.6/pear:/usr/local/bin:/etc/pki/tls/certs) in <b>/home/u737470708/public_html/cursoFullStack/symfony/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php</b> on line <b>35</b><br />